# nginx mask or convert query string to different url

Tags: nginx, php, web-server, rewrite, php-fpm

I want to convert or mask a url with query string to another url.

From:
https://www.example.com/world/web/?q=hello

To:
https://www.example.com/world/web/search/hello

I have tried everything on google including this code too:

```
location ~ /world/web {
    if ($args ~* "^q=(.*)") {
        set $myparam $1;
        set $args '';
        rewrite ^.*$ /world/web/search/$myparam permanent;
    }
}
```

It is showing new URL but I am getting 404 Not found error.
I want to display everything from original url (https://www.example.com/world/web/?q=hello
) but I want client browser to see different url (https://www.example.com/world/web/search/hello)

I am using fastcgi php.

How can I achieve this? I am sure something is missing.

**Edit:**
Here is my full server block

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 http2;
    server_name  example.com;

   root /public/content/directory;

   location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

   location /world/web/search {
    rewrite ^/world/web/search/(.*)$ /world/web/index.php?q=$1 last;
   }

   location = /world/web/index.php {
     if ($request_uri !~ /world/web/search) {
        return 301 /world/web/search/$arg_q;
     }
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php73/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php73/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting in the wrong direction: the `/world/web/search/hello` URI path sent by the browser must be internally rewritten into `/world/web/index.php?q=hello` and passed to the PHP script.

Therefore you just need:

```
location /world/web/search {
    rewrite ^/world/web/search/(.*)$ /world/web/index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

**Edit:** As you pointed out in a comment, you want also prevent browsers from using the `/world/web/` and `/world/web/index.php` URI paths directly. In such a case you **still** need a `rewrite` directive as above (which is the cause of your `404` errors, since a file named `/world/web/search` does not exist) and you need to add something like this:

```
location = /world/web/index.php {
    if ($request_uri !~ /world/web/search) {
        return 301 /world/web/search/$arg_q;
    }
    # Your PHP config, e.g.:
    # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}
```

The main risk in this configuration is to fall into a redirect loop. This would happen if you used:

```
rewrite ^/world/web/index.php$ /world/web/search/$arg_q permanent;
```

in the second `location`, since `rewrite` matches against the `$uri` variable, which is rewritten by internal redirects. `$request_uri` does not suffer of this problem.

Comment: No. Actually, when user click on the link https://www.example.com/world/web/?q=hello then I want them to see this url https://www.example.com/world/web/search/hello in their browser URL bar
 but I want to show the content of original url which has query string

Comment: 1) User clicks on this link -> https://example.com/world/web/?q=hello
2) Nginx rewrites or mask the url so browser takes it to ->  https://example.com/world/web/search/hello

3) User see content of this url -> https://example.com/world/web/?q=hello

I am trying to normalize the url because query string is a cache burster.

Comment: I edited the answer according to your clarifications. Basically you need an internal rewrite and an external redirect and to take care not to fall into a loop.

Comment: Can you please tell me what fastcgi config should be added there since I have already fastcgi declared in server block for root '/'
Because I m getting blank page

Comment: You probably have a `location ~ \.php$` or similar defined. Just copy the FastCGI directives in there. You should check **Nginx**'s error log (usually `/var/log/nginx/error.log`) and use `curl -i http://example.com/uri_path` for testing.

Comment: This is not working. I am getting 404 not found.  If I curl  example.com/world/web/search/hello  I don't see content of url with query.

Comment: The other `location`s you have in your `server` block can influence the `location` selection algorithm: e.g. `location ~ /world/web` takes priority over `location /world/web/search`. Can you add to your question all your `location` directives?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please let me know why it didn't work.

Comment: Any luck so far? Im terribly stuck on this.

Comment: The `server` block you posted works as required. You should check your nginx **error log** for the reason of the `404` error. It might also be generated by your script.